# charCodeAt not supported in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm using the following function to encode strings into base64:

```
encode: function(input) {
    var output = "";
    var chr1, chr2, chr3;
    var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;

    do {
        chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

        enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
        enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
        enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
        enc4 = chr3 & 63;

        if (isNaN(chr2)) {
            enc3 = enc4 = 64;
        } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
            enc4 = 64;
        }

        output = output + this.keyStr.charAt(enc1) + this.keyStr.charAt(enc2) + this.keyStr.charAt(enc3) + this.keyStr.charAt(enc4);
    } while (i < input.length);

    return output;
}
```

However in IE, I'm getting the following error:

```
 chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
 "Object doesn't supported by this property or method".
```

Could you please help me fix that? It appears that the charCodeAt function isn't working.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `charCodeAt()` is supported in IE 5.5+. Are you still supporting < IE 5.5? If you are, please stop. ;-).

Comment: I am using IE 11 but still this code not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sure *looks* like IE supports `String#charCodeAt()`: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charCodeAt.asp) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hza4d04f(VS.85).aspx).

What is `typeof input`?

Comment: I discovered that the type was "number" so I added a check such as if the type of input is not a string, it calls the toString() function to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really must* do this in < IE 5.5, then:

```
input.charAt(i++).escape()
```

will do what you want.

However, this fails on unicode characters, but in the dark days of IE 5.4 and below, unicode was nearly nonexistent.

If you are working in >= IE 5.5, then the problem is not with `charCodeAt()`, but rather with another part of your code. What is `input`?